# Should there be an "unclose" vote?

Tags: feature-request

people start voting to close a question and those who don't want it closed have to wait for the closers to gather their 5 votes and only then try to re-open it.  If they express their opinion earlier, perhaps the closers would see the writing on the wall and not put everybody through a lot of hassle.

Comment: You mean a vote which will negate the close vote? If so then that will not be right.. it will be undemocratic.. we should be able to vote and others should be able to do so too.. but our votes should not eradicate others' votes.. both should be accepted..

Comment: I am just saying let close and unclose votes be counted separately.  Closure takes place when closers exceed unclosers by 5.

Comment: Ok but unclose or open votes come into the picture only when a post is closed.. What is the justification behind unclose voting a post that is yet to be closed?

Comment: Somebody suggested exactly what I suggested and received lots of upvotes.  How come they haven't acted on it?

Answer (score 5):

It's discussed at many threads in main meta. [This thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54890/163449) links to 3 other posts:

- [How about a "Vote not to close" option to counter the "Vote to close"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close)
- [Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)
- [You should be able to vote to reopen a question before it is actually closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33259/you-should-be-able-to-vote-to-reopen-a-question-before-it-is-actually-closed)

It's a good suggestion, but opinions are varied.

Answer (score 4):

This feature already exists and it is a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Users with close vote privilege (Reputation 500) are able to vote to leave open a question in the review queues. If there are three "Leave Open"s in the [review queue](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/close), it will be out of the review queue and close votes starts aging.

[image: Picture of review queues Leave Open]

However, this vote doesn't override the close vote it got.

Comment: Nice, so there is a good balance between "direct unclose vote" and "no unclose vote" at all.